How do I implement a Splash screen for my app?
I have a simple test application, and I want to see how to add a splash screen to my app.  I tried using a popup for this (is there a better way?), and the popup will preferably have no buttons, just an image that lingers for a short amount of time, then the popup closes automatically.
What I have now seems to do nothing.  Here's my Python code:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

# below this kivy version you cannot use the app
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class LoadSplashScreenDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class LayoutTestApp(App):
    SplashImage = 'images/GrapeVineSplashText.jpg'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        content = LoadSplashScreenDialog(cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Test App", content=content, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0))
        self._popup.open()
        # self._popup.dismiss()

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()
    ...

I have a call to _popup.dismiss() after _popup.open(), but it is currently commented out, because I don't (yet) know how to wait for a specified amount of time before automatically closing the popup. So, at this point, I just want to see that the splash screen appears.
Here is my kv code:
<LoadSplashScreenDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        Image:
            id: image
            source: app.SplashImage
            fit_mode: "contain"     # resized to fit, maintaining aspect ratio
            padding: 2
            size_hint_x: 1.0
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1  # ? gray color
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

Am I close?  Am I way off?  How would I get this to work???

I found a solution for adding a splash screen.  It suddenly occurred to me that having the popup code in my app's __init__() method could be the cause of the problem, because the app might not be finished initializing and therefore not ready to display a popup.
Moving the popup code to my app's build() method also did not work, probably for similar reasons.
So I coded the following:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._popup = None

    def build(self):
        # show splash screen immediately after build() completes
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ShowSplashScreen, 0)
        return self.mainLayout

    def ShowSplashScreen(self, *args):
        content = LoadSplashScreenDialog(cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Test App", content=content, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0))
        self._popup.open()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 2)

By scheduling the popup to display in the next frame, it will display immediately after the build() method completes and the app is instantiated.

First, you need to load the kv. Perhaps like this:
kv = '''
<LoadSplashScreenDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        Image:
            id: image
            source: app.SplashImage
            fit_mode: "contain"     # resized to fit, maintaining aspect ratio
            padding: 2
            size_hint_x: 1.0
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1  # ? gray color
                Line:
                    width: 2
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

I think you can use Clock.schedule_once() to schedule the close of your Popup:
    self._popup.open()
    Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 2)

And add *args argument to the dismiss_popup() method:
def dismiss_popup(self, *args):
    self._popup.dismiss()


I added *args to dismiss_popup() (though there was no indication Python had a problem with it before). And I added this line:  Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup(), 2), but I now get an error message when I run the program: "File "C:\Projects\LayoutTest\main.py", line 58, in init|:| Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup(), 2)|:| File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 480, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once|:| File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 502, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once|:|
ValueError: callback must be a callable, got None" (Note that I replaced newlines with '|:|')

OK, sorry - I see now that I should not have included the parentheses on dismiss_popup. (I'm actually surprised that it wasn't flagged by the IDE...)  Anyway, I'm back to my original problem:  the splash screen does not appear at all.

And I neglected to mention earlier that I do not "need to load the kv." That is done automatically, as evidenced by the rest of my app displaying as described in the kv.

That will work if you kv file is correctly named. Your post does not provide the name of your kv file.
